# how to ignore the .htaccess file from a parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm using rewrite rules for search engine optimized url's
In my root folder I have the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{http_host} ^elitegameservers.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.elitegameservers.net/$1 [R=301,L]
rewriteEngine on
rewriteBase /
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)haloservers(.nl|.us|.net)$
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.haloservers.net/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?haloservers(.nl|.us|.net) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.elitegameservers.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In the sub directory(/controlpanel) I run WHMCS with the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^elitegameservers.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.elitegameservers.net/controlpanel/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteEngine On

# Announcements
RewriteRule ^announcements/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./announcements.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^announcements$ ./announcements.php [L,NC]

# Downloads
RewriteRule ^downloads/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ ./downloads.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^downloads$ ./downloads.php [L,NC]

# Knowledgebase
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+\.html$ ./knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ ./knowledgebase.php?action=displaycat&catid=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^knowledgebase$ ./knowledgebase.php [L,NC]
```

I noticed that knowledgeable SEO optimization in WHMCS doesn't seem to work properly and it seems to be caused by the .htaccess code in my root directory.

Because of that I want the controlpanel sub directory to be excluded from the code in the root directory.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a condition to the rules in your root directory to exclude requests starting with `controlpanel`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/controlpanel
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)haloservers(.nl|.us|.net)$
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.haloservers.net/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/controlpanel
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?haloservers(.nl|.us|.net) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.elitegameservers.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```